# Does every non-singleton connected metric space $X$ contains a connected subset (with more than one point) which is not homeomorphic with $X$?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, connectedness

Does every non-singleton connected metric space $X$ contains a connected subset (with more than one point) which is  not homeomorphic with $X$ ?

Also ; does every connected metric space $X$ contains a connected subset which is  homeomorphic with $X$ ?

UPDATE : So as noticed by @orangeskid ; the answer to the 2nd question is "no" by considering $X=S^1$ . The first question still remains unanswered

Comment: See the [Knuster-Kuratowski fan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knaster%E2%80%93Kuratowski_fan)

Comment: @Teri : How does that help ?

Comment: interesting question.  I can show it is true for compact Hausdorff spaces.  my intuition says it should be true. I am working on a proof by cases.

Comment: @ForeverMozart : You can show it for compact connected Hausdorff spaces ? Could you please take the trouble to write that out in comment or as an answer ; It would be very very helpful . Thanks in advance

Comment: @SaunDev See my question (and answer) here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1572687/compact-connected-space-is-the-union-of-two-disjoint-connected-sets . Every cpt Haus. space is the union of two disjoint connected subsets.  At least one must be non-compact, thus not homeomorphic to the entire space.

Answer (score 4):

Take $X$ a $1$-dimensional circle. $X$ does not contain any proper subspaces homeomorphic to a circle, since any connected proper subspace is a segment.

${\bf Added:}$

The answer to the first question is yes for spaces that contain a segment. It seems a lot of connected metric spaces contain a segment.

Comment: Okay , so that answers the 2nd question ; what about the first one ?

Comment: @Saun Dev: This post http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/796635/every-metrizable-toronto-space-is-discrete seems to be related to your question