# Separation axioms and when does there exist a connected space all whose proper connected subspaces are homeomorphic to the whole space?

Tags: general-topology, connectedness, separation-axioms

This question is in the spirit of this question [Does every non-singleton connected metric space $X$ contains a connected subset (with more than one point) which is not homeomorphic with $X$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1584373/does-every-non-singleton-connected-metric-space-x-contains-a-connected-subset)    ; Fixing the convention that whenever we will talk about connected spaces or subsets we will talk about such with more than one point ; it is easy to observe that $\mathbb Z$ with co-finite topology fails to have the property mentioned in the question i.e. the space is connected and every proper connected subset is homeomorphic to the whole space . Now this counter example space  is $T_1$ but not Hausdorff , nor regular , nor normal . So it is natural to ask : Does there exist a connected Hausdorff ( resp. for Regular , $T_3$ ,  Normal , $T_4$ ) space such that every proper connected subspace of it is homeomorphic to the whole space ?

Comment: It's not a counter example, but an example: the integers in the cofinite topology has the interesting property that it is connected and every non-empty connected subset of it is homeomorphic to the whole space. Now you wonder whether examples with higher separation properties exist as well. The integers in the cofinite topology *do* have the property in the title.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma : They do have the property in the title of "this question " but not of the "other question " concerning metric spaces ; but anyways it's ok that you got the spirit of the question . Have you any other examples with higher separation properties ?

Comment: If you change the condition from "proper connected subspace" to "proper connected _open_ subspace", then $\mathbb{R}$ is an example (it's Hausdorff, regular, T3, normal and T4). https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/239063/intervals-are-connected-and-the-only-connected-sets-in-mathbbr